# How to execute code with nunit at start only

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit

I'm using the latest NUnit to run Selenium tests. The tests are compiled into a class library DLL file which is then run by NUnit.
My problem is that before the automation begins, I need to run some initialization such as creating a log file, setting up specific parameters, etc. I don't see a way to do this in NUnit - setup() does this but for every Test or Fixture - I just need to run this code once at the start of the application.
Any idea how I can do what I want?
Your help is very appreciated.
J.

Comment: Well it depends, "at the start" has many meanings. How are your tests run now? Just manually through NUnit? Not through any CI software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at `SetUpFixtureAttribute` ([more information here](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=setupFixture&r=2.6.2)). It says:

> This is the attribute that marks a class that contains the one-time setup or teardown methods for all the test fixtures under a given namespace. The class may contain at most one method marked with the SetUpAttribute and one method marked with the TearDownAttribute.

Comment: Thanks meilke. I was looking at an earlier version of the online help and didn't see this. It does exactly what I need. Great stuff!